# How to optimize web application updating cycle

Tags: node.js, gulp, forever

I have a `Node.js` application that uses [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to generate the ready-to-run version in the `build` directory.

Suppose that I started my application via [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever), and after some peroid of time I try to generate a new build. What is the correct way to accomplish the update-and-restart task in this case? I think that I can't just run the `gulp` task again because files in the `build` directory are used by the currently running instance of the application, and I can't just stop this instance because I don't want users to see the moment when the server is shut down.

What is the best way to minimize the server downtime in this case?

Comment: Claster with two nodes - something like http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-node-js-cluster-for-speeding-up-your-apps/ . When one node is down (application is updated) the socond one runs for a moment with previous version of your application.

Comment: @Krzysztof Safjanowski As far as I understood, all application's instances of the cluster will use the same directory so I don't quite understand how it'll work when I decide to update all files used by application. Could you provide a detailed answer, please?

Comment: cluster is proof of concept, let me google some solutions for you: http://cjihrig.com/blog/scaling-node-js-applications/

Comment: @Krzysztof Safjanowski I think that there should be much easier-to-use solution like `naught` -- https://github.com/andrewrk/naught. Did you try to achieve zero down-time in Node.js applications by yourself?

Comment: Not for NodeJS ; / I've used clusters for `PHP / Symphony 2` application. The idea should be almost the same. `naught` looks promising